# Strange numbers in jQuery (13.700000000000001)

Tags: jquery

Let's say I add up two numbers:

```js
const total = (parseFloat(10) + parseFloat(3.7)).toFixed(2)
console.log(total)
```

`console.log` prints out **13.70**, but if I put **total** into a div as text `$('div').text(total)`, it shows 13.700000000000001

Can't figure out where 00000000000001 comes from.

Comment: [Works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/q7kuz81n/).  If you update the question to a runnable code snippet as a [mcve], does it demonstrate the problem?

Comment: Welcome to floating point math! This has nothing to do with jQuery. I recommend taking a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript - I converted the code in your question into a snippet and `total` logs out `13.70` as you said. This is due to the `toFixed(2)` you added